# UDEV rules for launching scripts when DVD loaded (multiple drives)

Tags: udev

Ok so I'm trying to run a headless makemkv server and while I have my script working perfectly, I'm missing something for the udev rules.  Below is what I have for rules:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sr0", ENV{ID_CDROM_MEDIA_DVD}=="1", ACTION=="change", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/makemkv.sh sr0"
SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sr1", ENV{ID_CDROM_MEDIA_DVD}=="1", ACTION=="change", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/makemkv.sh sr1"
SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sr2", ENV{ID_CDROM_MEDIA_DVD}=="1", ACTION=="change", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/makemkv.sh sr2"
SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sr3", ENV{ID_CDROM_MEDIA_DVD}=="1", ACTION=="change", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/makemkv.sh sr3"
SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sr4", ENV{ID_CDROM_MEDIA_DVD}=="1", ACTION=="change", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/makemkv.sh sr4"
```

How should I call the script and TELL the script which DVD drive had the disc inserted?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can [use string globbing](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#strmatch) to match multiple values and [place holders](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#strsubst) inside assignment:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sr?*", ENV{ID_CDROM_MEDIA_DVD}=="1", ACTION=="change", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/makemkv.sh %k"
```

For more info see “[Writing udev rules](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html)”.